# ERROR Compiled without LIBSSH v0.4.x support, module is not available

Tags: macos, libssh, hydra

I'd like to toy with hydra on my OSX, but I can't figure out what's the problem.

```
brew info hydra
```

output:

```
hydra: stable 8.3 (bottled), HEAD Network logon cracker which supports
many services https://www.thc.org/thc-hydra/
/usr/local/Cellar/hydra/8.3 (14 files, 1.2M) *   Poured from bottle on
2016-08-20 at 15:28:25 From:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/hydra.rb
==> Dependencies Build: pkg-config ✘ Required: openssl ✔ Optional: subversion ✘, libidn ✘, libssh ✔, pcre ✘, gtk+ ✘
==> Options
--with-gtk+     Build with gtk+ support
--with-libidn   Build with libidn support
--with-libssh   Build with libssh support
--with-pcre     Build with pcre support
--with-subversion   Build with subversion support
--HEAD  Install HEAD version
```

When I try to launch:

```bash
hydra -l user -P /Users/alex/Downloads/list_pwd.txt 192.168.1.3 ssh
```

I get:

```
[ERROR] Compiled without LIBSSH v0.4.x support, module is not
available!
```

Answer (score 16):

Just came across this error today and it seems they don't actually compile it with hydra for some reason but it should be easy enough to do manually. 
This is what I did to get it working:

```
brew uninstall hydra 
brew install -v --with-libssh hydra
```

That should compile hydra with appropriate ssh module and should be good to go `-v` option just to confirm there were no actual errors with libssh when compiling.